# How to make sure correct include and linking paths are set for downstream projects when making library with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I've been trying to follow the following link to make sure that I'm doing things completely/correctly, and also so that I might expand on what I'm doing later by e.g. adding components, adding different version requirements for some libraries, etc. In short, I'm trying to be on the road to knowing what I'm doing with CMake instead of cobbling things together with tidbits I find on the Internet. The problem is, that after following along with this tutorial in the documentation, I've apparently broken my stuff such that my downstream projects that include this library can't build or link to it (I presume the appropriate include and linker paths aren't getting set).

The link: [cmake guide: adding export configuration](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html)
In doing so, I've added a minimal Config.cmake.in, *ConfigVersion.cmake, *Targets.cmake, and automagically exported a *Config.cmake file per what you see in that guide.

Prior to making these changes, what I had looked like this: (effectively only used the exported targets)

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config 
    Library
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/rms
    INCLUDES
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
export(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
)
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)
```

After following that document (as best I could anyway), what I've got is

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    Library
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/rms
    INCLUDES
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)
write_basic_package_version_file( 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION "${PROJ_VERSION}"
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)
install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)
```

Before I made the changes outlined above, downstream projects would link to this library fine, after they do not. To be abundantly clear, what I do in the downstream projects looks like this:

```
find_package(rms_utils) 
# ...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC rms_utils)
```

As stated above, after making this change, the downstream projects aren't finding includes or linking as appropriate. What do I need to change to resolve this.

An example error, per request in comments:

```
/opt/rms/src/rms/core/src/genericsweep.cpp:12:10: fatal error: 'rms/plugin.hpp' file not found
```

full text of CMakeLists.txt

```
###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 1. Required CMake Version #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 2. Package Name and Version #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

set(VERBOSE 1)
add_link_options("LINKER:-v")
file(READ "VERSION" ver_raw_in)
string(REGEX MATCH " _version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(PROJ_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
string(REGEX MATCH ".*_soversion=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(PROJ_SOVERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_sdr_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(SDRIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_portswitcher_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(PSIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_powermeter_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(PMIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_transmitter_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(TXIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_receiver_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(RXIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(SPECANIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

string(REGEX MATCH ".*_rms_interface_powermeter_version=([0-9\.]+).*" _ ${ver_raw_in})
set(SPECANIFACE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")

project(rms_utils
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION ${PROJ_VERSION}
    DESCRIPTION "library supporting core RMS functionality")

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 3. required build definitions and options #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/rms CACHE PATH "comment" FORCE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)

option (FORCE_COLORED_OUTPUT "Always produce ANSI-colored output (GNU/Clang only)." TRUE)
if (${FORCE_COLORED_OUTPUT})
    if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
       add_compile_options (-fdiagnostics-color=always)
    elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
       add_compile_options (-fcolor-diagnostics)
    endif ()
endif ()

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 4. find all depdendency packages #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/qt-rms/")
find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Core Sql REQUIRED)

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 5. set up build targets #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

set(
    PROJ_SOURCES
        src/baseworker.cpp
        src/complex.cpp
        src/iqbuffer.cpp
        src/logging_core.cpp
        src/plugin.cpp
        src/stopwatch.cpp
        src/utilities.cpp
)
set(
    PROJ_INCLUDES
        include/consoletext.hpp
        include/complex.hpp
        include/iqbuffer.hpp
        include/constants.hpp
        include/logging_core.hpp
        include/plugin.hpp
        include/rmsutils_global.hpp
        include/stopwatch.hpp
        include/utilities.hpp
        include/baseworker.hpp
        include/singleshotworker.hpp
        include/continuousworker.hpp
)
set(
    INTERFACES
        rms_interface_sdr
        rms_interface_portswitcher
        rms_interface_transmitter
        rms_interface_receiver
        rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer
        rms_interface_powermeter
)
set(SDR_INCLUDES include/sdrinterface.hpp)
set(PORTSWITCHER_INCLUDES include/portswitcherinterface.hpp)
set(TRANSMITTER_INCLUDES include/transmitterinterface.hpp)
set(RECEIVER_INCLUDES include/receiverinterface.hpp include/collectiqtask.hpp)
set(POWERMETER_INCLUDES include/powermeterinterface.hpp)
set(SPECTRUMANALYZER_INCLUDES include/spectrumanalyzerinterface.hpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
        ${PROJ_SOURCES}
        ${PROJ_INCLUDES}
)
add_library(rms_interface_sdr SHARED
    ${SDR_INCLUDES}
    src/sdrinterface.cpp)
add_library(rms_interface_portswitcher SHARED
    ${PORTSWITCHER_INCLUDES}
    src/portswitcherinterface.cpp)
add_library(rms_interface_transmitter SHARED
    ${TRANSMITTER_INCLUDES}
    src/transmitterinterface.cpp)
add_library(rms_interface_receiver SHARED
    ${RECEIVER_INCLUDES}
    include/collectiqtask.hpp)
add_library(rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer SHARED
    ${SPECTRUMANALYZER_INCLUDES}
    src/spectrumanalyzerinterface.cpp)
add_library(rms_interface_powermeter SHARED
    ${POWERMETER_INCLUDES}
    src/powermeterinterface.cpp)

string(TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARY UPPERNAME)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_sdr PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_portswitcher PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_transmitter PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_receiver PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})
target_compile_definitions(rms_interface_powermeter PRIVATE ${UPPERNAME})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJ_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${PROJ_SOVERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PROJ_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_sdr
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${SDRIFACE_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${SDRIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${SDR_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_portswitcher
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PSIFACE_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${PSIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PORTSWITCHER_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_transmitter
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${TXIFACE_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${TXIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${TRANSMITTER_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_receiver
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${RXIFACE_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${RXIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${RECEIVER_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${SPECANIFACE_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${SPECANIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${SPECTRUMANALYZER_INCLUDES}"
)
set_target_properties(rms_interface_powermeter
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PMIFACE_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${PMIFACE_VERSION}
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${POWERMETER_INCLUDES}"
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_sdr
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_portswitcher
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_transmitter
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_receiver
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(
    rms_interface_powermeter
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 6. Link against external libraries #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}                Qt::Core Qt::Sql fftw3)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_sdr              Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils rms_interface_transmitter rms_interface_receiver)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_portswitcher     Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_transmitter      Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_receiver         Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_spectrumanalyzer Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils)
target_link_libraries(rms_interface_powermeter       Qt::Core Qt::Sql rms_utils)

###########################################################
###########################################################
##### 7. Install #####
###########################################################
###########################################################

##### all changes that I made when following the guide mentioned in the post happened below this line ######

# this is what I had previously

#install(
#    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
#    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
#    LIBRARY
#        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
#    ARCHIVE
#        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
#    RUNTIME
#        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
#    PUBLIC_HEADER
#        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/rms
#    INCLUDES
#        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
#    )

#export(
#    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
#    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
#    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
#    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake")
#install(
#    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
#    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake")


# and this is what I have now
install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${INTERFACES}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    LIBRARY
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/rms
    INCLUDES
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    )
    
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)
write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION "${PROJ_VERSION}"
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)

### for cmake debugging purposes

get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
list (SORT _variableNames)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

Linking would also fail (building without cleaning won't need to find headers, but will still fail on trying to link)

--- edits 2022/03/26
added an example error message, fixed an error in what I typed here for the target_link_libraries line that a downstream project might use, added full text of the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: "my downstream projects that include this library can't build or link to it" - Too vague description of the problem. Please, provide (add to the question post) the **exact error message**, so we could be able to identify the problem. BTW, `target_link_libraries(rms_utils)` is definitely wrong as it misses the first argument of the function, which should point to a downstream target.

Comment: I've made a few corrections and added a few things. I think the error is exactly what you might expect given the description. I've also made the title *a little* less vague, I think.

Comment: Original project installs EXPORT file **without** NAMESPACE option, so in `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC rms_utils)` the `rms_utils` actually represents a target. Modified project installs EXPORT file **with** option `NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::`, so it should be used via `rms_utils::rms_utils` instead.